# When Hibernate does not generate optimal query. How to make hibernate generate optimal query

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, orm

While ORM frameworks like hibernate does simplify the activities of accessing and modifying data in RDBMS. And it's features like lazy loading, caching etc also help in better application performance when used properly.
But what I am thinking of is if the query generator or optimizer is not using the best query - say not following the proper ordering of tables during a join and not using the most suitable join strategy etc.
**How can i optimize the query or say hibernate to generate a better query which is more optimal than the one it is generating by default.**

(probably if I am not wrong,  this question applies to other ORM frameworks like iBATIS etc also)

**EDIT following answer from S. Bhattacharjee** -  I would also hope that Hibernate will generate the best optimal query.  But on the other side even when using Oracle SQL executor in Oracle GUI,  it's some time the case that the Optimizer DOES NOT use optimal plan. But I can influence it by writing the query more specifically. (don't ask me how it's done, if some one knows please indicate. I am no SQL expert. I need to analyse this case to ensure the systems flexibility and optimization's are not limited because of frameworks). So
**CASE 1** - consider hibernate is not generating optimal query. So how to influence it to generate optimal query.
**CASE 2** - hibernate is generating optimal query. But SQL engine is using a plan that is not optimal. Query and Plan (or execution) are different from my understanding. I am not sure if this is a valid case or not. So ignore if not applicable.  But if anyone think this is a valid case even if they can't answer, plz leave a comment to bolster this point.

Next speaking about Hibernate query generator - another question pops in to my mind. Does Hibernate know about the Logical Structure of DB (I don't expect it to know the physical design anyway and may not be relevant to consider it here).
a) If it does know logical db design, how does it know about it.
b) if it does not know logical db design, then how can it be sure about the query being optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my opinion hibernate generates a good and optimal query. Please be more clear on what grounds you are saying so, may be with an example? However if you want you may write your own SQL queries. Below is a very small example

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select c.codename from 
codes c where c.code = :paramcode")
.setParameter("paramcode", "900");
List result = query.list();
```

Comment: Great about the confidence you have on hibernate but I want to still look at it atleast theoretically and if it is possible to influence hibernate in query generation. And I am aware of adding native sequel code, but that is not I am looking for here.

Comment: Thank you, I will also look forward to this if something positive comes up!!